# Items move on top of each other android

Tags: android, layout

I have a screen with 5 edittext, 5 buttons which appears correctly as in you can see the screenshot [image]

when i input text the items move on top of each other like in second screenshot, how can i fix this?[image]

here is my xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnGoHome" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSaveList"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Save" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/saveList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSaveList"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSaveList"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Create Shopping List" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnViewItems2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnGoHome"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnGoHome"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="View Items" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGoToShop2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddItem"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Go To Shop" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGoHome"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnGoToShop2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnGoToShop2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Home" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addQuantity"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Add Item" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spShoppingList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnViewItems2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSaveList"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addShop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addQuantity"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addQuantity"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Add Shop" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addShop"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addShop"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Add Item" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Quantity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following for your activity in Manifest (for all those activities where you have this problem):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

eg:

```
<activity
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
   <intent-filter >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
```

For more details go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried yours and Sir SC and both works well.

Comment: Accept the answer as i pointed out that first @LetmeSuckitBaby

Answer (score 2):

From project manifest, inside your ***activity*** tag, add code:

For keyboard to be **visible** on start

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

For keyboard to be **hidden** on start

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: in all of my activity tags, i have five activities?

Comment: Accept my answer as i was the one who pointed out the solution first.. @Letme